# Only expand one bootstrap 4 collapse at a time

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have this HTML where it is going to have multiple Bootstrap 4 collapse cards. I need for it to only open one at a time and if another is opened all sibling cards collapse must hide. Please look at my codepen.

https://codepen.io/sazad/pen/XPWXYR

The function I am trying to write I am not sure why it is not rendering anywhere. Right now it is just a console.log but Please guide me in the right direction of making this possible.

Please view codepen to see the HTML working with the JQuery.

```
function expandOneOnly() {
 if ($(".panel").find(".collapse").hasClass("show")) {
     console.log("hi");
 }

function enableNotification() {
$('.notify-check').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.panel').find(".caret-icon").toggleClass("hide");
    $(this).closest('.panel').find(".disabled-overlay").toggleClass("hide");
    $(this).closest('.panel').find(".select-text-display").toggleClass("hide");
    if ($(this).closest('.panel').find(".collapse").hasClass("show")) {
        $(this).closest('.panel').find(".collapse").toggleClass("show");
        $(this).closest('.panel').find(".caret-icon").toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
    }
     expandOneOnly();
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
overlayWidth();
enableNotification();
expandSelection();
frequencySelection();  
});
```

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis for the first if statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify this so that the handler only has:

```
function enableNotification() {
    $('.notify-check').change(function() {
        var panel = $(this).closest('.panel')
        $(this).closest('.row').children().removeClass('active')
        panel.addClass('active')
     });
}
```

and then you have this in your CSS:

```
.active .disabled-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.active .caret-icon,
.active .select-text-display,
.active .collapse {
  display: inherit;
}
```

This way you only handle the current item and add `active` class and for all others you simply remove that class. The CSS takes care of the rest.

[Here is this working](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLWXXQ)

Comment: You could could remove the `.not()` function by changing it to: `$(this).closest('.row').children().removeClass('active'); panel.addClass('active')` :)

Comment: Even better! Thanks :)

Comment: @ChrisHappy  I'm sorry those solutions did not work. I also looked at the "Here is this working" codepen and it is buggy. when the switch comes on the overlay must disappear and on click of the price title is when the expand is suppose to show. if the switch goes off expand needs to collapse. If you click the other price title the expand on the first price should collapse but the overlay must not come back on.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below worked out pretty well.

```
function expandSelection() {
$(".btn-title").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".caret-icon").toggleClass("fa-caret-up fa-caret-down");
    if ($(this).closest(".panel").siblings().find(".collapse").hasClass("show")) {
        $(this).closest(".panel").siblings().find(".collapse").removeClass("show");
        $(this).closest(".panel").siblings().find(".caret-icon").toggleClass("fa-caret-up fa-caret-down");
    }
});
}
```

Check out updated Codepen for full HTML, CSS, JQuery code: https://codepen.io/sazad/pen/XPWXYR

Thanks everyone!